# User input program to determine the minimum and maximum value [one edge case is not working]

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following program that asks the user to enter a number and takes in that many values. The goal here is to determine what the minimum and maximum values are based on the user input. Most use cases work, but when you enter a sequence, i.e. `1, 2, 3, 4` or `2, 3, 4, 5` the output for minimum is always `min: 0`. I can't figure out a way to handle this situation. Can anyone help guide me in the correct direction?

```py
num_of_iters = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(f"Please enter {num_of_iters} number.")

maximum = 0
minimum = 0

for i in range(0, num_of_iters):
    num = int(input())
    
    if num >= maximum:
        maximum = num
    if num <= minimum:
        minimum = num
        
print("min: ", minimum)
print("max: ", maximum)
```

Comment: `0` is not a reasonable value to use here. Consider `float('-inf')` and `float('inf')`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I would disagree. Initializing a variable with `inf`s is something that I haven't seen. 0 is reasonable because a user isn't going to input super long ints. IMHO

Comment: What about *negative integers*? And frankly, not having seen something isn't really a convincing argument against it. The entire purpose of these numbers is to serve as numbers were these comparisons are always true.

Answer (score 2):

None of the numbers you've input are less than `0`, so the minimum is never updated.

You should modify that condition so that it updates on the first number.

```
    if i == 0 or num <= minimum:
        minimum = num
```

### Functional Approach

Alternatively, if you want to get fancy, we can do this as a one-liner using `functools.reduce` and the `:=` operator. I'm going to draw it out a bit more for demonstration.

```
from functools import reduce

init_min = float("inf")
init_max = float("-inf")
init = (init_min, init_max)

num_inputs = 5

min, max = reduce((lambda init, _: (init[0], n) if (n := int(input())) > init[1] else (n, init[1]) if n < init[0] else init), range(num_inputs), init)
```

We only want the input number once, so we use `:=` to bind the result of `int(input())` to `n` *and* return the value so it can be used.

We test this value against our initial min and max and modify the tuple at each iteration accordingly. In the end, the tuple we get has the min and max values.

Answer (score 0):

You're initialising `minimum` to zero, and when a sequence is entered that contains only numbers larger than zero, that value never changes (because the `if num <= minimum:` block never gets executed). What you can do is to initialise `minimum` to a number that you know will be higher than any number ever entered, e.g. 1000. That would be analogous to initialising `maximum` to zero, a number that's lower than any number that will ever be entered, but that's error-proof and not very Pythonic. A safer bet might be to initialise `minimum` and `maximum` to `None` and to test, in the `if` blocks, if `minimum` is less than the existing `minimum` or to zero, and to set it to the current `num` if so (analogous for `maximum`).